# Алгоритм оптимизации SQL

Tags: sql, оптимизация, mysql

Смотрите есть база данных, допустим в ней одна таблица, в которой один столбец. Столбец `id`, ну и в нем такие значения: `1,2,3,6,7,9,12`.
Как (скажите алгоритм) при помощи `SQL` и `PHP`, можно сделать такие значения: `1,2,3,4,5,6,7`, то есть заново проиндексировать?

Comment: то есть добавить недостающие элементы?

Comment: А можно полное описание таблицы? Есть ли ключи и ограничения на это поле? Тип поля и т.д. А то вопрос сводится к "у меня есть машина, как поменять колёса"?

Answer (score 3):

Если id - инкрементное поле, то вариант такой:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `tab_temp` SELECT * FROM `tab`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `tab`;
INSERT `tab` (`field1`, `field2`) SELECT `field1`, `field2` FROM `tab_temp`;
```

Comment: И ВСЕ? Там же вроде нужен UPDATE

Comment: [И все](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/50443/1)

Comment: `create table as select * from table` такой вариант не прокатит? (кей филд может быть автогенерированым или же подставлять из sequence)

Comment: @jmu ну idшники останутся старыми, в общем будет не проще. не знаю, зачем это действие ТС, но думаю, что это однократная операция.

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется, что придется всю таблицу считывать в массив (`$arr[$key]`), где `$key` и есть ваш `id`. Потом этот массив надо вручную отсортировать. Я написал простой пример [тут](http://codepad.org/LrcPQoTe).

Сразу предупреждаю, что идея не претендует на 100% правильность, если найдется более простое, быстрое и умное решение, буду очень рад)

Comment: протестю, если все ок - отмечу

Comment: Подождите лучше немного, может найдется лучше вариант.

Comment: а еще обратно закачивать, как в цикле7

Comment: там же нужно сделать UPDATE, вот в чем проблема

Comment: Хм, UPDATE в цикле это конечно очень плохо. Как вариант, можно попробовать запомнить измененные поля и потом уже их проапдейтить.