# Изменение значения поля по порядку. SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

В бд есть таблица с id 1 5 6 20 25
Как написать запрос,что б переименовать айди по порядку,тоесть в конце должно быть 1 2 3 4 5, что б первый остался 1,второй(=5) стал 2 и т.д.?

Comment: А диалект SQL какой ?

Comment: mysql postgesql

Comment: Плохая практика изменять значения ID. Вы стреляете себе в ногу и просите вам помочь. Смысл первичного ключа в однозначной идентификации записи, а не в нумерации по порядку. Счетчик автоинкремента может опять оставить "дырку" при неудачной операции и это нормально! А для красоты вывода достаточно иметь переменную-счетчик в шаблоне.

Comment: да.Я понимаю Вас. Но у меня каскадно подвязаны таблицы,тоесть после переименовывания во всех таблицах тоже изменятся данные и пока ссылок на айди пользователей нет,так что внешне для пользователей ничего не изменится

Comment: Дело ваше, конечно, просто смысла в этом нет, если таблицы "живые". Сегодня сделаете по порядку, завтра увидите новые дырки. Кстати, если не сделаете ALTER TABLE, то дырка вам гарантирована сразу же при первом инсерте.

Comment: Как раз вот дырки и хочу залатать, а новая система будет добавлять по порядку. А предыдущая добавляла айди немного "от потолка"

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/226524/

Answer (score 4):

MySQL:

```
update testN set id=(select @a:=@a+1)
  where (select @a:=0)=0
  order by id
```

Postgresql (id должны быть уникальны):

```
update testN A set id=num
  from (
   select id,row_number() over(order by id) num
     from testN
  ) B
 where B.id=A.id
```

Comment: Еще, вероятно, придется сбросить auto_increment счетчик

Answer (score 0):

Такое решение отвечает стандарту SQL и должно работать на большинстве диалектов:

```
UPDATE tab u
SET u.id = (
    SELECT newid FROM (
        SELECT id, row_number() OVER (ORDER BY id) newid FROM tab) t 
    WHERE t.id = u.id)
```

Answer (score -1):

Обычно "номер по порядку" нужен только в Представлении. Для реляционной базы это неестественно.

На примере PHP:

```
$i = 1;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) {
  echo ($i++).' '.$row['id'].' '.$row['name']."<br>\n";
}
```