# mysql: упорядочивание разорванной произвольной сортировки

Tags: mysql

Есть следующая таблица:

```
+----+--------+------+
| id |  name  | sort |
+----+--------+------+
|  1 | Илья   |  1   |
|  2 | Денис  |  14  |
|  3 | Сергей |  10  |
+----+--------+------+
```

Как мне сделать UPDATE поля sort таким образом, чтобы значения разорванной сортировки стали упорядоченными (1, 2, 3), но при этом сама сортировка осталась неизменной (т.е Илья - 1, Денис - 3, Сергей - 2).

Comment: 1 вопрос: зачем?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Изменение значения поля по порядку. SQL](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/501275/%d0%98%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8f%d0%b4%d0%ba%d1%83-sql)

Comment: В том ^ ответе вместо `id` разумеется `sort`. т.е. `update testN set sort=(select @a:=@a+1)
  where (select @a:=0)=0
  order by sort`

Comment: Отлично! Огромное спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE
    <ИМЯ ТАБЛИЦЫ> as t,
    (SELECT id, @i:=@i+1 as it FROM <ИМЯ ТАБЛИЦЫ>, (SELECT @i:=0) foo ORDER BY sort) as s
SET t.sort = s.it
WHERE t.id = s.id
```

Comment: Запрос пронумеровал позиции по порядку, без сохранения актуальной сортировки. Но спасибо за ответ, все равно