# Инкрементировать столбец в mysql

Tags: mysql

Необходимо пробежать по столбцу и расставить для первичного ключа цифры по порядку,т.к после удаления возникают пробелы.
Пытаюсь выполнить так
SET @x=1; UPDATE table_order SET id_order = @x Where @x=@x+1;
Но ничего не обновляется

Comment: Вас не должны волновать пробелы в ключах.

Comment: то то и оно что мне нужно чтобы пробелов не было

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Изменение значения поля по порядку. SQL](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/501275/%d0%98%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8f%d0%b4%d0%ba%d1%83-sql)

Comment: Только обращаю ваше внимание, что в 99% случаев это не требуется и очень вредно. возможно вы подошли к задаче не стой стороны, раз вам это потребовалось. Потому как любые выборки данных можно написать так, что бы им не требовалось отсутствие пропусков.

Comment: Не могу с вами не согласится! Просто в этой таблице первичный ключ используется для вывода по порядку и больше в других таблицах не используется.Поэтому засунув запрос SET @x=0; UPDATE table_order SET id_order = (SELECT @x:=@x+1);

Comment: в тригер я обеспечиваю себе непрерывность номера попорядку при удалении записи

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь!