# После удаления записей прервалась сквозная нумерация в таблице

Tags: sql, база-данных, phpmyadmin

В phpMyAdmin удалил три строки из таблицы `id=15,16,17`:

[image: удалил три строки из таблицы]

Теперь, при добавлении через `<form...>` на сайте в таблице создаётся строка с id не по порядку (12,13,14,18).

ОТВЕТ

> "НУЖНО НАПИСАТЬ СКРИПТ ПРОВЕРКИ И СДЕЛАТЬ ++"

ЗНАЮ

Есть ли средство восстановить сквозную нумерацию?

Comment: А для каких целей вам нужны номера строго по порядку ? Разрывы в нумерации, это абсолютно нормальное явление и оно у вас будет возникать на каждом шагу. И если оно вам чем то мешает, то скорее всего что то не правильно спроектировано. Но если очень хочется ... https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/501282/194569

Comment: ID - это не номер по порядку. Это внутренний идентификатор, который вообще не желательно ни менять ни показывать вовне.

Comment: Научный интерес, так сказать

Comment: Получается, что ключь устанавливает не порядковый номер, а номер операции добавления строки

Comment: И в таблице хранится информация о том, сколько вообще было создано строк за всё время её существования

Comment: А вот где хранится эта информация и можно ли её менять? Суть первого вопроса в этом

Answer (score 2):

> Есть ли средство восстановить сквозную нумерацию?

Нет, потому что никакого порядка записей в БД не существует.

Но можно сделать сквозную нумерацию записей в результате запроса на основании его сортировки:

```sql
set @rownum := 0; 
select @rownum := @rownum+1 as rownum, id from (
    select 1 as id union all
    select 2 as id union all
    select 9 as id
order by id asc
) q

rownum  id
------  --
1       1
2       2
3       9
```

Если это не то, что нужно, то вы явно делаете что-то не то.

[На fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f7cf8ed622545b20cd0c02c545586cf7).