# Как вычислить сумму значений колонки MySQL в одном запросе вместе с UPDATE?

Tags: php, mysql

Делается UPDATE в таблицу MySQL. UPDATE устанавливает числовые значения decimal(32,8) одной колонки в таблице. В этом же запросе используются WHERE, то есть UPDATE производится не по всем строкам, а только по определенным.

Вопрос: как сделать так, чтобы в этом же запросе получить сумму значений, которые сделал UPTATE в этой одной колонке? С одной стороны, можно сделать отдельный запрос SELECT SUM, но так не получится, поскольку невозможно будет точно идентифицировать после UPDATE, какие именно строки в колонке он затронул. Можно ли как-то сделать SELECT SUM по пройденным строкам методом UPDATE в одном с ним запросе и вывести затем значение SELECT SUM в PHP переменную?

Comment: в mysql нельзя. но обходных вариантов вагон

Comment: @Ипатьев, Благодарю за ответ. Если не сложно, можете привести несколько примеров таких обходных вариантов?

Comment: ну например селектом выбрать сумму и id всех строк попавших под условие. и потом по этим же id сделать апдейт. ну или в три притопа: селект, апдйет, селект суммы

Comment: @Ипатьев, благодарю, подумаю над этим вариантом.

Comment: Вот тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/501275/#501282 есть пример нумерации с помощью переменной строк при update. Точно так же можно накапливать в переменной сумму значений по мере update. И что самое главное, значение в переменной остается доступным после завершения операции (пока жива сессия) и его можно получить другим запросом `select @a`

Comment: @Mike благодарю за совет, но пока немного не пойму как именно можно задавать переменную суммы накоплений вместе UPDATE? Я понимаю, что накопление должно выглядеть примерно так: `@total := @total + @update_amount `, но как сделать это в одном запросе вместе с UPDATE, не подскажете пример?

Comment: А откуда берутся значения которые update ставит в поле. приведите текущий запрос обновления в общем виде

Comment: И да, если это просто значение, возможно придется схитрить написав что то вроде `set field = case when (@total := @total + @update_amount) is not null then @update_amount end`

Comment: @Mike, таким образом нужно узнать сумму значений `@cume_amount`, которые записал UPDATE

Comment: ну вот как я выше написал попробуйте, весь свой расчет поставьте внутрь when, а в then @cum_amount, раз уж он у вас уже в переменной

Comment: @Mike Благодарю за подсказку, сделал так, работает 

Comment: @Mike, подскажите такой момент, если не сложно. Ниже в следующем комментарии полный запрос, который я сделал благодаря вашему совету, только добавил еще WHERE. Вот только переменная '@cume_amount'  в WHERE почему-то не воспринимается и она там (в WHERE) похоже равна нулю, хотя другие переменные там вместо нее вроде бы работают. Не подскажете, почему такое может быть?

Comment: UPDATE `equiry_exchange_orders` SET available_amount_crypto_currency = CASE WHEN (@total_paid := @total_paid + @cume_amount := (@sum := @sum - (initial_amount_equiry * 0.46656841)) + (initial_amount_equiry * 0.46656841)) is not null THEN @cume_amount END WHERE (@cume_amount + (initial_amount_equiry * 0.46656841)) > 0 AND `type` = 'withdraw' ORDER BY `time_order_created` ASC

Comment: все операции в части update (как и при select) выполняются после того как набор строк над которым выполняться уже известен, т.е. после того как where закончит работу. Соответственно where видит переменную в момент начала запроса

Comment: @Mike, то есть эту переменную можно определить например только в WHERE а, дальше передавать уже как переменную?

Comment: можно и до запроса ее определить. мне просто больше нравится все в пределах одного запроса делать. И вы бы лучше задачу описали. Я не понимаю чего вы пытаетесь достичь при этом обновлении. Может посчитать все в select запросе и сделать его join в update

Comment: @Mike, я подробно описал суть запроса и задачи в новой теме (так как там вопрос в основном уже про WHERE): https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1234622/Как-поставить-переменную-в-where-из-этого-же-запроса-mysql посмотрите пожалуйста, если вам не сложно. Как вы считаете, какое будет наилучшее решение для этого?