# Как поставить переменную в WHERE из этого же запроса MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Есть вот такой запрос:

```
UPDATE `equiry_exchange_orders` SET available_amount_crypto_currency = CASE #Если заявка на обмен может быть выкуплена полностью WHEN (@total_paid := @total_paid + @cume_amount := (@sum := @sum - (initial_amount_equiry * 0.46656841)) + (initial_amount_equiry * 0.46656841)) is not null AND @cume_amount >= initial_amount_equiry * 0.46656841 THEN initial_amount_equiry * 0.46656841 #Если заявка на обмен может быть выкуплена только частично WHEN (@total_paid := @total_paid + @cume_amount := (@sum := @sum - (initial_amount_equiry * 0.46656841)) + (initial_amount_equiry * 0.46656841)) is not null AND @cume_amount < initial_amount_equiry * 0.46656841 THEN @cume_amount + (initial_amount_equiry * 0.46656841) END WHERE (@cume_amount) > 0 AND `type` = 'withdraw' ORDER BY `time_order_created` ASC
```

Суть запроса в следующем:
В таблице есть заявки на обмен. И есть изначально определенная сумма `0.46656841`, которой нужно "выкупить" только те заявки, которые эта сумма сможет выкупить. То есть берется значение столбца `"initial_amount_equiry"` и смотрится, может ли сума `0.46656841` его "выкупить". Если может полностью, то в столбец `"available_amount_crypto_currency"` записывается значение из `"initial_amount_equiry"`, а остаток суммы `0.46656841` сравнивается со значением столбца `"initial_amount_equiry"` следующей строки и опять проверяется - может ли уже остаток "выкупить" это полностью или нет. Если может, то так продолжается далее. А если сумма `0.46656841` может "выкупить" значение из `"initial_amount_equiry"` только частично, то рассчитывается сумма, которая по сути осталась от `0.46656841` и записывается в `"available_amount_crypto_currency"`. 
В настоящий момент запрос работает следующим образом: в заявки, которые сумма `0.46656841` может "выкупить" записываются положительными числа в колонку `"available_amount_crypto_currency"`, а дальше в другие колонки записываются числовые значения уже со знаком "-" (минус).

**Вопрос:** как сделать так, чтобы минусовые значения не записывались? То есть записывалось только то, что реально может "выкупиться"? Для этого я пробую сделать `WHERE (@cume_amount) > 0`, но насколько я уже понял, то переменная `@cume_amount` еще равна нулю, так как возможно еще не посчитана на этом этапе запроса. Подскажите, как можно все-таки переменную `@cume_amount` использовать в `WHERE` или каким-либо другим образом "отсечь" минусовые значения? Важно, чтобы строки, где могут быть минусовые значения просто не попадали в UPDATE, именно для этого я и хотел использовать `WHERE`. Может быть есть другие решения?

Comment: update trigger  ?

Comment: @splash58 Это как? Вы не могли бы написать пример, если вам не сложно?

Comment: для начала убедитесь, что mysql на вашем хосте разрешает делать триггеры - это не везде. А так, примеров полно в сети. Если что-то конкретное не получится, спрашивайте

Comment: Какая точно версия MySQL?

Comment: @Akina, Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.4.11-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2

Comment: Я верно понимаю, что Вы хотите получить что-то типа вот такого: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=31fbaead218b23ac5a76fef17e0c3f0b ?

Comment: @Akina, да, что-то типа такого. Я так понимаю, там WHERE не нужен, как в моей задаче, так как работает SELECT с условиями? Если Вам не сложно, можете написать как запрос из того примера будет выглядеть в описанной мной задаче?

Comment: Вот только расчётный запрос - так проще? https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=72e81703f172369bc8d754b3a72aa26e *можете написать как запрос из того примера будет выглядеть в описанной мной задаче?* Да я в этой лапше вообще ничего не  понял... куча переменных, куча присвоений - да застрелиться.

Comment: @Akina, благодарю. Попробую взять за основу.

Comment: В любом случае общий подход - сперва получите нужные данные в SELECT, а потом из него обновляйте в другой копии таблицы.

Comment: @Oleg Я правильно понимаю что в вашей версии уже доступны оконные функции ? (попробуйте на какой нибудь небольшой табличке скажем `select field1, sum(field1) over(order by field2) from table` где field1 числовое поле

Comment: И да, akina прав, сначала выбираем точно то, что хотим поменять, потом меняем. но могут быть еще нюансы связанные с блокировками. И еще со структурой не совсем ясно. Запрос я так понимает меняет встречные ордера для исполнения текущего. но что если для текущего не хватит встречных ордеров, он будет исполнен значит не полностью и надо будет в нем еще фиксировать не обменянный объем ? И как сохраняется история какой ордер за счет какого был выполнен ? мне кажется это важная информация для последующего разбора полетов, если что то пошло не так

Comment: @Mike, да, оконные функции доступны.

Comment: @Mike, Да, запрос меняет встречные ордера для исполнения текущего. Если для текущего не хватит встречных, то есть переменная `@total_paid`, в которую записывается сумма того, на что встречных хватило. А затем уже будет вычисляться сколько осталось обменять в текущем запросе, грубо говоря `0.46656841 - @total_paid`. Я предполагал, что сначала будет `SELECT FOR UPDATE` строки с текущим ордером на "покупку", чтобы его заблокировать на время выполнения `UPDATE`, который описал в топике, а затем делать еще один `SET` в этом же `UPDATE`, где уже записать не обменянный объем текущего.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set @need = 210;
update equiry_exchange_orders o
  join (
    select id, new_avail, @need := @need - new_avail
      from (
        select *, case when remain >= 0 then init else @need - prev_sum end new_avail
          from (
            select *, sum(init) over(order by id)-init prev_sum, @need-sum(init) over(order by id) remain
              from equiry_exchange_orders
        ) x 
      ) y
    where new_avail > 0 for update
  ) n on o.id=n.id
  set avail = new_avail
```

На начало запроса в переменную `@need` помещается сумма которую необходимо списать. Запрос пишет в колонку avail сколько было списано из данной записи (полная сумма или остаток). После выполнения запроса в переменной @need остается сумма, на которую не хватило заявок. В order by внутри over указать желаемый порядок исполнения ордеров (сейчас по id записей)

Пример на [dbfiddle.uk](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=ec505dc7ee6e8ef4591b40d70a8f493f)

Comment: @Oleg Вложенность запросов совершенно не страшно. Оптимизатор не делает все именно так как написано. Только от количества записей во внутреннем подзапросе зависит.

Comment: да, согласен. Но если все-таки это делать в этом одном запросе, то как это сделать более правильно? Если взять на примере dbfiddle, который вы делали выше, я добавил в нем две колонки. Просто задача желательно не разбивать это на разные запросы, но если вдруг не получится, то на крайний случай можно.

Comment: то есть WHERE type = "exchange" в самом внутреннем SELECT в таком случае делать не нужно?
В таком случае запрос UPDATE ведь будет проходить по всем строкам и WHERE type = "exchange" и WHERE type = "get" если в самый внутренний SELECT не поставить WHERE type = "exchange"?
Я просто думал можно сделать как-то UNION например с самым внутренним SELECT и указать в нем WHERE type = "get" AND id = 5 LIMIT 1, чтобы в запрос не попадали все get-ордера, а только один, которому и нужно записать значение '@need'. Примерно так как-то возможно?

Comment: да, вы правы, '@need' изначально берется из поля init именно этой записи с type="get" (у записей есть еще колонка type, которая может быть либо change, либо get), значение поля avail_get которой нужно поменять на новое значение '@need'. Если вам не сложно, вы не могли бы привести пример такого UNION, который вы предложили применительно к вашему примеру?

Comment: да, есть еще изначально и id записи, в которую нужно записать новое значение '@need'. Проверка на get это перестраховка, на всякий случай (так как id не порядковые, а генерируются автоматически), однако шанс что id повторятся практически отсутствует, поэтому на get можно в принципе и не проверять.

Comment: @Oleg https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=ca9662ceeaa3e7ead6204ebe6f4b1d73  Старые комменты почистите что бы не засорять ответ

Comment: @Oleg Вот так https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=2b6b51eb71ce958ad4e9d821c6729ade лучше. Что бы for update для get записи был взят раньше и вообще избавиться от union

Comment: благодарю за ответ и за пример! 

Comment: заметил такую особенность. Если добавить в таблицу колонку 'date' и добавить в нее сначала уникальные даты и время, например 2021-01-16 17:10:05, 2021-01-16 17:11:05, 2021-01-16 17:11:05, а затем несколько одинаковых дат 2021-01-16 17:12:05, то если в 'over(order by id)' вместо 'id' поставить 'date', то 'avail' перестанет добавляться ровно там, где начинаются одинаковые даты. Но если добавить к order by date значение DESC, то все работает нормально. Таким образом ASC по date в SUM OVER с одинаковыми датами и временем почему-то работает не корректно. Не могли бы подсказать, почему так?

Comment: Если я ставлю все даты разными, то такой проблемы не возникает. Также, если я ставлю order by id, то также все хорошо. Получается, что тут в order by должны быть только уникальные значения?

Comment: Также интересный момент, если я добавляю колонку test_id в таблицу и прописываю там сначала числовые значения к полям по порядку сверху вниз от 1 и далее (1, 2, 3, 4, 5 и т.д.) а потом например от числа 11 прописываю далее только число 11, то есть до 11 числа идут по порядку, а начиная с 11 число 11 дублируется вниз и в order by добавляю эту колонку ('test_id'), то avail добавляется абсолютно ко всем строкам, даже к тем, к которым не должно добавляться. А если в колонке test_id сделать все числа по порядку без дублей, то avail записывается как надо.

Comment: Получается, 'order by' тут как-то странно себя ведет. Подскажите пожалуйста, из-за чего это и как это можно исправить?

Comment: Пример этой особенности 'order by' на вашем примере на dbfiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=6fac26f051a49a65c9c72bc4bd5a0529

Comment: @Oleg Поведение мне то же кажется странным. postgresql повторяет такое же поведение, значит это закономерность. не знал о ней. и значит надо добавить в сортировку еще и id после даты для надежности

Comment: А две сортировки подряд как будут работать? Сначала сортируется по одной, затем по другой или как-то по другому?

Comment: @Oleg Сортировка одна `order by x, y`. сначала сортируется по x, для одинаковых значений x по y

Comment: @Oleg Еще рекомендуют явно указывать что нужна кумулятивная сумма `over(order by test_id rows between unbounded preceding and current row)`

Comment: Благодарю за ответ. `over(order by test_id rows between unbounded preceding and current row)` можно прямо так и указывать применительно к вашему примеру на dbfiddle? На что это может повлиять?

Comment: Кстати попробовал указать `over(order by test_id rows between unbounded preceding and current row)` и только с одним order by test_id даже с дублями в test_id вроде бы теперь работает корректно: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=6fac26f051a49a65c9c72bc4bd5a0529 Но нужно ли теперь указать дополнительно order по id: 'order by test_id, id' на всякий случай или теперь можно не указывать?

Comment: @Oleg нет, не нужно, если не важно в каком порядке списание проходит внутри даты

Comment: Благодарю. Внутри даты - что вы имели в виду? Списание по идее должно происходить по дате - от более старой к более новой. Вы наверное имели виду, если попадутся одинаковые значения даты, в каком порядке именно по ним будет происходить списание? Если так, то получается что можно указать дополнительно id для order by, в случае, если даты будут одинаковыми, то чтобы внутри одинаковых дат тоже по порядку происходило списание?